# Not able to locate element using following-sibling or following in Appium for Mac

Tags: xpath, appium, xcuitest, appium-java, xcuielement

I'm trying to locate the checkbox in the below xml path using xpath following-sibling. But unable to locate the element.

Following is the xml.

```
    
        <XCUIElementTypeScrollView elementType="46" identifier="_NS:429" label="" title="" enabled="false" selected="false" x="460" y="312" width="521" height="210">
      
            <XCUIElementTypeOutline elementType="29" identifier="_NS:433" label="" title="" enabled="true" selected="false" x="461" y="341" width="519" height="180">
        
                <XCUIElementTypeOutlineRow elementType="30" identifier="" label="" title="" enabled="false" selected="false" x="461" y="341" width="519" height="20">
          
                    <XCUIElementTypeGroup elementType="3" identifier="" label="" title="" enabled="false" selected="false" x="461" y="341" width="300" height="20">
            
                        <XCUIElementTypeDisclosureTriangle elementType="13" identifier="" value="0" label="" title="" enabled="true" selected="false" x="463" y="342" width="13" height="17"/>
            
                        <XCUIElementTypeStaticText elementType="48" identifier="" value="Desktop" label="" title="" enabled="true" selected="false" x="476" y="342" width="284" height="17"/>
          
                    </XCUIElementTypeGroup>
          
                    <XCUIElementTypeCheckBox elementType="12" identifier="" value="2" label="" title="" enabled="true" selected="false" x="762" y="342" width="17" height="17"/>
        
                </XCUIElementTypeOutlineRow>
```

Tried following xpaths already but not able to locate the element 'XCUIElementTypeCheckBox'.

`"//XCUIElementTypeStaticText[@value='Desktop']/following-sibling::XCUIElementTypeCheckBox"`

`"//XCUIElementTypeOutlineRow[XCUIElementTypeStaticText[@value='Desktop']]/following::XCUIElementTypeCheckBox"`

`"//XCUIElementTypeStaticText[@value='Desktop']/following::XCUIElementTypeCheckBox"`

I'm stuck at this point. As I'm kinda new to Appium for Mac, I'd really appreciate any help in locating the checkbox using xpath or any other way.

**NOTE**: I haven't attached the entire xml as its too huge.

Comment: For that sample as posted I think only `//XCUIElementTypeStaticText[@value='Desktop']/following::XCUIElementTypeCheckBox` will select that eement `XCUIElementTypeCheckBox`; the other two expressions don't select anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following sibling selects element that shares the same parent node, `<XCUIElementTypeStaticText` and `XCUIElementTypeCheckBox` aren't siblings.

Sibling of your element is only `XCUIElementTypeGroup`
, which are sharing `XCUIElementTypeOutlineRow` as parent.

***Using following-sibling:***

```
//XCUIElementTypeStaticText[@value='Desktop']/parent::*/following-sibling::XCUIElementTypeCheckBox
```

or

```
//XCUIElementTypeGroup/following-sibling::XCUIElementTypeCheckBox
```

***Using child of parent:***

```
//XCUIElementTypeOutlineRow/*[2][self::XCUIElementTypeCheckBox]
```

Modify these xpaths' according to your whole xml document.

If you will be working with xpaths', you can check out my [github project](https://github.com/riflosnake/XPanther) that finds unique xpath selector for you. Any support is greatly appreciated.

Comment: xpath using chil element worked perfectly! I just wanted to know if I can locate the checkbox with reference to 'XCUIElementTypeStaticText' with value 'Desktop'  as I have multiple checkboxes in the xml and I need to differentiate each checkbox.

Comment: @Harish then you need to get the parent of `XCUIElementTypeStaticText`, and then the following sibling. Check my updated answer.

Comment: Yes. That updated solution worked. Thanks a lot for the help. I just wanted to clarify one more thing. What does * speifies in the first xpath you mentioned and also, what does *[2] specifiy in one more xpath you mentioned in your answer? One more query is, why do we use self :: in xpath?

Comment: * means match anything, in `*[2]` means match the second child, that could be any element. `*[2][self::XCUIElementTypeCheckBox]` means select the second child, if only it is of type `XCUIElementTypeCheckBox`.